# How to include "Chapter" in chapter cross references?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Suppose I have a document structure like this and I am using `hyperref`:

```
Chapter 1 \label{chapter:one}
  Section 1 \label{sec:one}
Chapter 2
...
```

If I input

```
\ref{chapter:one}, \ref{sec:one}
```

I get

```
1, 1.1
```

I want to get instead:

```
Chapter 1, Section 1.1
```

Can I get this within `hyperref`? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `hyperref` you can use `\autoref`, like `\autoref{chapter:one}`, `\autoref{sec:one}`

If you want to get Chapter and Section instead of chapter and section, you can redefine the auto referencing names to be used.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\chapterautorefname{Chapter} % use Chapter instead of chapter <<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand\sectionautorefname{Section} % use Section instead of section <<<<<<<<<<<
    
\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{One}\label{chapter:one}        
    
    \section{First}\label{sec:one}
    
    \chapter{Two}
    
    \autoref{chapter:one}, \autoref{sec:one}    % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<      

\end{document}
```

[image: b]